# Why 'make test' and "./test/Test"

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, googletest

Now I'm setting up a c++ test environment with CMake. Actually I've realized what I want to do, but I'm confused by 2 different test output style.
In my example below, what 'make test' do actually? I think both 'make test' and './test/Test' output are same, but not exactly. 'make test' output is different from googletest output style. Although test results looks same, I couldn't be satisfied with these output.

**Output Differences**

```
$ make test                 
Running tests...
Test project /path/to/sample/build
    Start 1: MyTest
1/1 Test #1: MyTest ...........................***Failed    0.02 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.02 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - MyTest (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] エラー 8

$ ./test/Test               
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from MyLibTest
[ RUN      ] MyLibTest.valCheck
/path/to/test/test.cc:10: Failure
      Expected: sqr(1.0)
      Which is: 1
To be equal to: 2.0
      Which is: 2
[  FAILED  ] MyLibTest.valCheck (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] MyLibTest.negativeValCheck
[       OK ] MyLibTest.negativeValCheck (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from MyLibTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] MyLibTest.valCheck

 1 FAILED TEST
```

**Commands**

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make test   // NOT googletest output style
./test/Test // It looks googletest output
```

**My Environment**

```
root
 - CMakeLists.txt
 + src/
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - main.cc
   - sqr.cc
   - sqr.h
 + test/
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - test.cc
```

**root /CMakeLists.txt**

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 project (MYTEST)

 add_subdirectory(src)
 add_subdirectory(test)
 enable_testing()
 add_test(NAME MyTest COMMAND Test)
```

**test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
 set(GTEST_ROOT /path/to/googletest/googletest)
 include_directories(${GTEST_ROOT}/include/)
 link_directories(${GTEST_ROOT}/build/)
 add_executable(Test ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.cc)
 target_link_libraries(Test sqr gtest gtest_main pthread)
```

**test/test/cc**

```
 #include "../src/sqr.h"
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>

 namespace {
   class MyLibTest : public ::testing::Test{};

   TEST_F(MyLibTest, valCheck) {
     EXPECT_EQ(sqr(3.0), 9.0);
     EXPECT_EQ(sqr(1.0), 2.0); // it fails!
   }

   TEST_F(MyLibTest, negativeValCheck) {
     EXPECT_EQ(sqr(-3.0), 9.0);
   }
 }
```

Comment: CMake / CTest will redirect a test executable's output to logfile. Check `Testing/Temporary/LastTest.log`. What you see with `make test` is the **CTest** output, which only shows the end result.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the behaviour of ctest (which is what make test will ultimately execute) with environment variables.

For example:

```
CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 make test
```

This will print full output for test executables that had a failure.

Another one you may be interested in is `CTEST_PARALLEL_LEVEL`

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. I could also confirm this by 'ctest --output-on-failure'. But I found if there are no errors, output style is different from googltest one. Anyway I could clear my thought.

Comment: @jef if the return code of the test executable is 0, ctest consumes all output so you don't see it. If you want to see all the output, try `ctest --verbose`